# How to distinguish mouse “click” and “drag” div table column in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I need to make a logic for resize column. This table is custom and with divs and spans elements.

That means for building this table is using just pure html and SCSS (not some external library).

Now I should make the columns to be vertical resizable. I need to understand how to make the logic for this resize.

And part which is not clear for me is main logic for this, that means:

1. When you click and drag column right border
2. Then should apply some css styles and update the width of column ?
3. Which event need for this, mousemove?

Code:

```
<div class="nano-table-row nano-table-grid-header"> 
   <!-- This columns should be resizeable -->
    <div 
        class="{{column.columnClass}}"
         *ngFor="let column of columnsArray"
         [ngClass]="{'sort-active':sortField === column.columnField}"
         (click)="onSortFieldChange(column.columnField)">
        <span>
            {{column.columnName}}
        </span>
        <i class="fa"
           [class.fa-sort-asc]="sortInverse === true && sortField === column.columnField"
           [class.fa-sort-desc]="sortInverse === false && sortField === column.columnField">
        </i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also in the project I found some custom directive for resize up and down, maybe this would be useful?

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[nanoResizable]'
})
export class ResizableDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    @Input() elementStyle: ModalStyle;

    private mouseDown: Subject<any> = new Subject();
    private mouseDrag: any;
    private mouseMove: Subject<any> = new Subject();
    private mouseUp: Subject<any> = new Subject();

    constructor() {
        this.mouseDrag = this.mouseDown
            .flatMap(
                startPos => this.mouseMove
                    .map((pos) => ({
                        width: pos.clientX - this.elementStyle.left,
                        height: pos.clientY - this.elementStyle.top
                    }))
                    .takeUntil(this.mouseUp)
            );

    }

    @HostListener('document:mouseup', ['$event'])
    onMouseup(event) {
        this.mouseUp.next(event);
    }

    @HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
    onMousedown(event) {
        this.mouseDown.next(event);
        return false; // Call preventDefault() on the event
    }

    @HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])
    onMousemove(event) {
        this.mouseMove.next(event);
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.mouseDrag
            .subscribe({
                next: pos => {
                    this.elementStyle.height = pos.height;
                    this.elementStyle.width = pos.width;
                }
            });
    }

    public ngOnDestroy() {
        this.mouseDrag.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Css code for ResizableDirective:

```
.nano-resize {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 7px;
    height: 10px;
    cursor: nwse-resize;
    z-index: 1;
   i {
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
     margin: auto;
   }
}
```

Here is the Style of table:

```
@import "../base/colors";

.nano-table-grid {
  //flex: 1;
  .nano-table-grid-header {
    > div {
      border-bottom: 1px solid $nano-dark-grey;
      //padding: 0 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-family: inherit !important;
      i {
        margin: auto 0 auto 2px;
      }
      &.sort-active {
        background-color: rgba(141, 192, 219, .25);
      }
    }
  }
  .nano-table-row-wrapper {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  }
  .nano-table-row {
    display: flex;
    padding: 5px 0;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    > div {
      flex: 1;
      display: flex; 
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0 2px;
      > span {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
    }
    .nano-table-placement-name-cell {
      flex: 2;
      flex-direction: column;
      span {
        margin: auto auto auto 0;
        max-width: 100%;
        &:nth-child(2) {
          //font-weight: bold;
        }
      }
      .tooltip-inner {
        max-width: inherit;
      }
    }

    .nano-table-entity-name-cell {
      flex: 3;
      flex-direction: column;

      span {
        margin: auto auto auto 0;
        max-width: 100%;
        &:nth-child(2) {
          //font-weight: bold;
        }
      }
      .tooltip-inner {
        max-width: inherit;
      }
    }
    .nano-table-name-cell {
      font-family: monospace;
      flex: 3;
      span {
        margin: auto 0;
      }
    }
    .nano-table-text-cell {
      font-family: monospace;
      flex: 2;
      span {
        margin: auto 0;
      }
    }
    .nano-table-placement-name-cell {
      min-width: 270px;
      span {
        margin: auto 0;
      }
    }
    .nano-table-number-cell {
      font-family: monospace;
      span {
        margin: auto 5px auto auto;
      }
    }
    .nano-table-actions-cell {
      min-width: 90px;
      flex: 2;
      justify-content: center;
      > span {
        padding: 5px;
      }
    }
    .nano-table-shrink-cell {
      flex: 0 0 50px;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .nano-table-expanded-cell {
      flex: 3;
    }
    .nano-table-preview-cell {
      height: 500px;
      flex: 0 0 100%;
      margin-top: 7px;
      margin-bottom: -5px;
      flex-direction: column-reverse;
      position: relative;
      .nano-entity-comment {
        height: calc(100% - 50px);
      }
      .nano-entity-header {
        display: none;
      }
    }
    &.opened {
      border: 1px solid $nano-white-smoke-darken;
    }
    &:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #fdfdfd;
    }
  }
}

.nano-table-footer {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  display: flex;
  .pagination-wrapper {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  .page-count-wrapper {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .pagination-item, .page-count-item {
    flex: 0 0 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    margin: 10px 2px;
    border: none;
    span {
      margin: auto;
    }
    &.pagination-item-active, &:hover, &:disabled {
      background-color: #e0e0e0;
    }
    &:disabled {
      cursor: not-allowed;
    }
  }
}*
```

Comment: @Random Yes, I didn't try with flex-flow. But for this table grid is used flex. 
I update the post with css file of table. 
You mean I should add display: flexbox and flex-flow: row wrap to the class of column?

Comment: Indeed you use flexbox, but so, can you make a JSfiddle, or an illustration of what you wish to achieve ?

Comment: @Random ok I will. Thanks.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/table/table.ts#L2388) is an angular table that allows column resize. But I guess it will be too much to explain and will be better if you come up with a more specific problem.

Comment: @sabithpocker Thanks for sharing this resource with me. 
Ok creating stackblitz code example for this issue.

Comment: It looks like this question has been abandoned. A [mcve] was promised but did not materialise, so I think it can be closed.